# Wikidata: QueryTimeoutException: Query deadline is expired

Tags: wikidata, sparql

I used to execute successfully the following query:

```
SELECT (COUNT(?r) AS ?count) WHERE { [] <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P31> ?r }
```

on `http://wdqs-beta.wmflabs.org/bigdata/namespace/wdq/sparql`

However, now this endpoint has been stopped, and when I execute the same query on official wikidata endpoint service: `https://query.wikidata.org` I get the following error:

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openrdf.query.QueryInterruptedException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.bigdata.bop.engine.QueryTimeoutException: Query deadline is expired.

This means that the query has exceeded the limit time.

Is there a way to expand executing time, or is there another SPARQL endpoint that allows me to execute the query?

Comment: What are you trying to do with your query? Other queries work fine.

Comment: it calculates frequency of using property P31. It is for research purposes.

Comment: P31 is "instance of" - how long did that take with the original web service?

Comment: I do not remember; it was calculated normally.

Comment: What are you trying to calculate?

Comment: How many entity have undirect/direct property P31 from/to other entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query is almost instant ([try it](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%28COUNT%28%2a%29%20AS%20%3Fcount%29%20%20%7B%20%3Fs%20wdt%3AP31%20%3Fo%20%7D)):

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) AS ?count)  { ?s wdt:P31 ?o }
```

---

In general, one have to download a [dump](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Database_download) and use it for such queries.

Another option is to use special reports (you should be especially interested in [this one](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Database_reports/List_of_properties/Top100)):

- [Wikidata database reports](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Database_reports)
- [Wikidata dashboards](https://grafana.wikimedia.org/dashboard/db/wikidata?orgId=1)
- [Wikimedia Statistics](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Statistics)

Additionally, property usage statistics is available on the [Property discussion](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property_talk:P31) page.

**Update**

[Hackish](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/REST_API#FAST_RANGE_COUNTS) way: [https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?ESTCARD&p=<http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P31>](https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?ESTCARD&p=%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2FP31%3E)

Comment: I know this is a bit old but could you perhaps elaborate on why the query you pasted is so much faster? I haven't seen a SPARQL query like that before, you have omitted the `WHERE` keyword, why is that? I tried to find an explanation but nothing mentions this. Why is your query *significantly* faster than the (semantically equivalent) query: `SELECT (COUNT(?s) AS ?count) WHERE {?s wdt:P31 ?o}`? Thanks